# Cannot enable events URL in Slack API

Tags: url, slack-api

This is my first post, and I'm a beginner at this so please be kind.

I'm running an integration on an AWS server, and the Slack API Enable Subscriptions page will not verify the Events Request URL. On the Slack API page, I receive the error "Your URL didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter." but no other information.

Following the instructions here: https://www.tyntec.com/docs/whatsapp-business-api-integration-slack

Everything looks OK until the Enable Events step. where Slack throws the following error:

[image: The error I recieved]

Here is the git repository https://github.com/tyntec/api-samples/tree/master/wa-integrations/slack

This is my postman code:

```
{
  "webhooks": [{
    "events": [
      "MoMessage"
    ],
    "callbackUrl": "https://x.x.x.x/tyntec/forwardWAMessage"
  }]
}
```

can you please nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring your Request URL, an event is dispatched to your endpoint including a `challenge` parameter. Your endpoint need to respond with a response body containing this exact `challenge` value to verify your endpoint.

You can find more detailed information in the **Request URL Configuration & Verification** section of the [Events API Configuration](https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions).